Implementation of Rate my app dialog on button press
I would like to give a pop up to rate my app which will redirect the user to google play store.
I have currently put a code to take the user directly to the playstore on click of a button.
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                const String packageName =     'com.mycompany.refereevision'; // Replace with your app's package name
                                                const String url =    'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName';

                                                if (await launchURL(url)) {
                                                  await launchURL(url);
                                                } else {
                                                  throw 'Could not launch $url';
                                                }
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ].divide(SizedBox(height: 30.0)),

A dialog like the one below is preferrable.


What is the question here?

Need to implement a pop up dialog on button press rather than taking the user directly to playstore as implemented above,
